# Dynamically generated lambda giving different result than regular lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-6

I am have a problem with Dynamically generated compared to a regular lambda expression in code.  Below is the code that I use to generate a dynamic lambda.

Dynamic Lambda for C

```
var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, propertyName);
MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });

var someValue = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));
var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, someValue);

return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsMethodExp, parameterExp);
```

Lambda from the debug view

```
{x => x.Name.Contains("UserName")}
```

But when I do the lambda in code like this

```
x => x.Name.Contains("UserName");
```

I get this for a result.  FormattedText is the variable used for regular lambda.

```
{x => x.Name.Contains(value(Test.BusinessLogicLayer.ClassBLL+<>x__DisplayClass8).formattedText)}
```

I use the lambda on the where clause on an Iqueryable object.  The dynamic lambda generates the SQL in Iqueryable with no SQL parameters.  The regular lambda causes the SQL to have parameters.  I would need it to generate with parameters.  We are looping through the  parameters to change the like to a contains so we can use Full Text search in SQL server.

My questions is, is there a way to dynamically generate the lambda to have the exact same output as the regular lambda?  Or is there a better way to use Full Text Search in Entity Framework 6?

Comment: The lambda you have pasted does not match the lambda you show in the debugger. I would suspect that you do not have a literal `"UserName"` argument, but instead are referencing a variable or property. Please paste the lambda *exactly* as it appears in your code, no munging please, no pseudo-code.

Comment: What is the concrete value of `T` above?

Comment: cdHowie.  I put a comment about FormattedText right above the out put.  Wanted to show that actual values in the lambda.

Comment: 500 - Internal Server Error, T represents any class that we need to generate the lambda for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are declaring the value as a constant (Expression.Constant) I would guess that EF simply generates that SQL without parameters, since it knows the constant can't change.

Perhaps you would be better off generating a lambda that explicitly takes the parameter as it's input ?

```
var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
var containsParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "p");

var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, propertyName);
MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });

var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, containsParameter);
```

Which would generate

```
(x, p) => x.Name.Contains(p)
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this and it doesn't work.  The lambda that is returned doesn't fit the <T, bool> requirement when I send it to the IQueryable object.